# View Component failed to fetch data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a problem with executing View Component in my .net Core web application. I've used it couple times before without a problem, but this time it is behaving little funny.

In the output window I can clearly see Visual studio is trying to query data from the database, but this command is being executed infinite number of items one by one many times per second until I stop the application (results of course don't render).

Also I've noticed that after a while used memory is about 2.5GB and is still increasing.

Anyone knows whats wrong? Any help greatly appreciated!

See the output window::

```
    Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2019-02-28T08:48:17.5125091Z","tags":{"ai.internal.nodeName":"V00X6036","ai.operation.name":"GET /DataTaxonomyTool/Index","ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"V00X6036","ai.location.ip":"127.0.0.1","ai.operation.id":"63f680a6-4a03a53f2cc95492","ai.operation.parentId":"|63f680a6-4a03a53f2cc95492."},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']\r\nSELECT [i].[Id], [i].[ObjectName], [i].[ObjectType]\r\nFROM [Items] AS [i]","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"commandText":"SELECT [i].[Id], [i].[ObjectName], [i].[ObjectType]\r\nFROM [Items] AS [i]","CategoryName":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command","DeveloperMode":"true","commandType":"Text","{OriginalFormat}":"Executed DbCommand ({elapsed}ms) [Parameters=[{parameters}], CommandType='{commandType}', CommandTimeout='{commandTimeout}']{newLine}{commandText}","elapsed":"1","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","commandTimeout":"30"}}}}
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
    SELECT [i].[Id], [i].[ObjectName], [i].[ObjectType]
    FROM [Items] AS [i]

Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2019-02-28T08:48:17.5378799Z","tags":{"ai.internal.nodeName":"V00X6036","ai.operation.name":"GET /DataTaxonomyTool/Index","ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"V00X6036","ai.location.ip":"127.0.0.1","ai.operation.id":"63f680a6-4a03a53f2cc95492","ai.operation.parentId":"|63f680a6-4a03a53f2cc95492."},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']\r\nSELECT [i].[Id], [i].[ObjectName], [i].[ObjectType]\r\nFROM [Items] AS [i]","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"commandText":"SELECT [i].[Id], [i].[ObjectName], [i].[ObjectType]\r\nFROM [Items] AS [i]","CategoryName":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command","DeveloperMode":"true","commandType":"Text","{OriginalFormat}":"Executed DbCommand ({elapsed}ms) [Parameters=[{parameters}], CommandType='{commandType}', CommandTimeout='{commandTimeout}']{newLine}{commandText}","elapsed":"1","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","commandTimeout":"30"}}}}
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
    SELECT [i].[Id], [i].[ObjectName], [i].[ObjectType]
    FROM [Items] AS [i]

Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2019-02-28T08:48:17.5612991Z","tags":{"ai.internal.nodeName":"V00X6036","ai.operation.name":"GET /DataTaxonomyTool/Index","ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"V00X6036","ai.location.ip":"127.0.0.1","ai.operation.id":"63f680a6-4a03a53f2cc95492","ai.operation.parentId":"|63f680a6-4a03a53f2cc95492."},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']\r\nSELECT [i].[Id], [i].[ObjectName], [i].[ObjectType]\r\nFROM [Items] AS [i]","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"commandText":"SELECT [i].[Id], [i].[ObjectName], [i].[ObjectType]\r\nFROM [Items] AS [i]","CategoryName":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command","DeveloperMode":"true","commandType":"Text","{OriginalFormat}":"Executed DbCommand ({elapsed}ms) [Parameters=[{parameters}], CommandType='{commandType}', CommandTimeout='{commandTimeout}']{newLine}{commandText}","elapsed":"1","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","commandTimeout":"30"}}}}
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
    SELECT [i].[Id], [i].[ObjectName], [i].[ObjectType]
    FROM [Items] AS [i]
```

View Component getMethod:

```
public class LayoutListsViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {

        DOOR.Core.Web.Models.ReportContext _context;

        public LayoutListsViewComponent(DOOR.Core.Web.Models.ReportContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public IList<DOOR.Core.Web.Models.DataTaxonomy.Item> items { get; set; }
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
        {
            var items = await _context.Items
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToListAsync();

            return View(items);
        }

    }
```

View Component Default.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<DOOR.Core.Web.Models.DataTaxonomy.Item>
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@{
    Layout = "~/Pages/DataTaxonomyTool/Layout/LayoutTaxonomy.cshtml";
}

@for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
{
    <ul style="list-style:none">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#@c.ToString().ToLower()">@c</a>
            <div id="@c.ToString().ToLower()" class="collapse">
                @foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(x => x.ObjectName))
                {
                    @if (item.ObjectName.StartsWith(c.ToString().ToLower()))
                    {
                        <ul style="list-style:none">
                            <li>@item.ObjectName</li>
                        </ul>
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
}
```

Layout:

```
@addTagHelper*,DOOR.Core.Web

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
<vc:layout-lists></vc:layout-lists>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me - when calling Default.cshtml I forgot to delete this part:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Pages/DataTaxonomyTool/Layout/LayoutTaxonomy.cshtml";
}
```

Im using this View Component to fetch some data in the same layout. So the program gets stuck in the infinite loop.